# Fill groups that have only zeros in them with NA

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, case, na

I obtained some old data which contain groups that hold only `0`s. I want to clean this dataset to use it for teaching. While some `0`s are naturally occurring in my data, it is not possible for a group to contain only `0`s. That leads me to the conclusion that observations in such a group can safely be labelled with `NA`s.

**Goal**

I wish that `0` should be replaced with `NA` **only if** the whole group is full of `0`.

**Reprex**

```r
library(dplyr)
df <- tibble(key_1 = rep(1:2, each = 4),
                 key_2 = rep(letters[1:2], each = 2, times = 2),
                 value = c(0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 2, 1, 0))
df
#> Output
# A tibble: 8 × 3
# key_1 key_2 value
# <int> <chr> <dbl>
#     1 a         0
#     1 a         0
#     1 b         0
#     1 b        -1
#     2 a         1
#     2 a         2
#     2 b         1
#     2 b         0
```

This data represents a situation where multiple key variables uniquely identify each group.

- In group `1a`, everything is `0`.
- In group `2b`, there is one `0`.

I expect `1a` to be filled with `NA`s while e.g. `2b` and other groups are preserved. I expect the solution to work within a `dplyr` pipeline, which is not mandatory, but it would be nice.

**Desired Output**

```
# key_1 key_2 value
# <int> <chr> <dbl>
#     1 a        NA
#     1 a        NA
#     1 b         0
#     1 b        -1
#     2 a         1
#     2 a         2
#     2 b         1
#     2 b         0
```

**Attempts so far**

I tried using `dplyr::case_when()`, and to set the normal values of the `value` column as a fallback. This throws the following error:

```r
df |> group_by(key_1, key_2) |>
  mutate(value = case_when(sum(value != 0) == 0 ~ NA,
                           .default = value))

#> Error:
# ! `.default` must have size 1, not size 2.
```

If I don't specify a default, everything is `NA`.

Providing some dummy value to default shows that the condition `sum(value != 0) == 0` is working correctly together with `group_by`.

```r
df |> group_by(key_1, key_2) |>
  mutate(value = case_when(sum(value != 0) == 0 ~ NA,
                           .default = "default"))
#> Output
# A tibble: 8 × 3
# Groups:   key_1, key_2 [4]
# key_1 key_2 value
# <int> <chr> <chr>
#     1 a     NA
#     1 a     NA
#     1 b     default
#     1 b     default
#     2 a     default
#     2 a     default
#     2 b     default
#     2 b     default
```

Comment: don't forget to `ungroup()` after grouping! Or use `.by = `

Comment: valid point. in my case I needed the groups afterwards, so it was OK to leave them. I like the `.by =` approach, as used in the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure you get an `NA` for each row. (`case_when` is a little stricter about recycling than base R. Here, your test value is length-1 for the group, and the result you specify, `NA`, is length-1, but the result you want has the same length as the number of rows in the group.)

```
df |>
  mutate(
    value = case_when(all(value == 0) ~ rep(NA, n()), .default = value),
    .by = c(key_1, key_2)
  )
# # A tibble: 8 × 3
#   key_1 key_2 value
#   <int> <chr> <dbl>
# 1     1 a        NA
# 2     1 a        NA
# 3     1 b         0
# 4     1 b        -1
# 5     2 a         1
# 6     2 a         2
# 7     2 b         1
# 8     2 b         0
```

Comment: Now I finally understand the `?case_when` documentation: „`.default` must be size 1 or the same size as the common size computed from `...`“ [where `...` are the used formulas `~`]. Your `~ rep(NA, n())` forces the „common size“ to equal the length of the current group, which enables the use of `value` as a default. This highlights pretty well what is happening in `case_when()` and why I got an error previously: Because my „common size“ was 1, as I only used `~ NA`. That is why I will accept this answer, even though the other answers are good as well.

Comment: Yeah, it would also work to repeat the test, `value = case_when(rep(all(value == 0), n()) ~ NA, .default = value)`, though that is less readable to me.

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be to use an `if ... else ...`:

```r
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

df |>
  group_by(key_1, key_2) |>
  mutate(
    value = if (any(value != 0)) value else NA
  )
#> # A tibble: 8 × 3
#> # Groups:   key_1, key_2 [4]
#>   key_1 key_2 value
#>   <int> <chr> <dbl>
#> 1     1 a        NA
#> 2     1 a        NA
#> 3     1 b         0
#> 4     1 b        -1
#> 5     2 a         1
#> 6     2 a         2
#> 7     2 b         1
#> 8     2 b         0
```

Comment: This is clearly the more elegant and readable solution. I only accepted the `case_when()` answer because it explains why my code was not working. For legibility and clarity, this one is my favourite.

Answer (score 1):

```
df |>
  mutate(all_0 = all(value == 0), .by = c(key_1, key_2)) |>
  mutate(value = if_else(all_0, NA, value))
```